# Emacs & Emacsclient not the same version

Tags: macos, emacs, homebrew

I have Emacs 24.3.1 on OS X installed via homebrew. However, my `emacsclient` is 22.1

Is there any way to get both up to the same version? Why are they not the same? On other machines, I've noticed both versions are the same and when Emacs is upgraded, emacsclient also gets an update.

Comment: Do a word search on your hard drive -- I'll bet you have a few emacsclient lying around.  Then do an `echo $PATH` in your terminal and see if the version you want is in the path.  You can also use the absolute path to the emacsclient you want, or fix the alias names for each version, or . . . . there are many different ways to resolve this issue.

Comment: OSX comes with Emacs -- on Snow Leopard, the executables are at `/usr/bin/emacsclient` and `/usr/bin/emacs`.  I recommend the following instead of homebrew:  http://emacsformacosx.com/  That way, everything is nicely packaged in one application, rather than scattering components of Emacs across your hard-drive.  Then you just need to worry about `.emacs.d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X comes with Emacs 22.2 preinstalled. Most probably you haven't adjusted properly your shell's `PATH` variable and this is causing the shell to pick up the built-in `emacsclient` instead of the one you installed via homebrew. Adding something like this to your shell's init file (`.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, etc) should fix your problem:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Alternatively (as suggested [here](http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Installing_Emacs_on_OS_X)) you can simply delete the bundled Emacs:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/emacs
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/share/emacs
```

The problem with the second approach is that OS X updates will restore the deleted Emacs 22, but they happen fairly rarely.

Comment: Interesting. Since `/usr/local/bin` is not in my path, how is it getting invoked when I call `emacs` in `/usr/local/bin`? Does homebrew take over if the bin wasn't found in PATH?